# reverse vowels in string in c

Tags: c, string

I'm a beginner programmer. I was trying out the problem of reversing vowels in a string.

Ex: input: zabedfigu, output: zubidfega

When I run the following code, I get a runtime error. I've tried to change the conditions within incrementing the pointer pc1 upto only upto the middle index etc., but that either gives me a runtime error or doesn't give me the required output. I'd like some help on what to do to make *my code work* as well as any new way of solving the problem. TIA.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* reverseVowels(char* str)
{
    char *pc1, *pc2;
    int i;
    pc1 = &str[0];
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0';++i)
        ;
    pc2 = &str[i-1];

    while(pc1!=pc2)
    {
      if((*pc1=='a')||(*pc1=='e')||(*pc1=='i')||(*pc1=='o')||(*pc1=='u'))
      {
        while(pc2!=pc1)
        {
            if((*pc2=='a')||(*pc2=='e')||(*pc2=='i')||(*pc2=='o')||(*pc2=='u'))
            {
              char temp;
              temp = *pc1;
              *pc1 = *pc2;
              *pc2 = temp;
              ++pc2;
              break;
            }
            else
              ++pc2;
        }
        ++pc1;
      }
      else
        ++pc1;
    }
    //return str;
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    char string[20], *pstr;
    scanf("%s", string);
    //pstr = reverseVowels(string);
    //printf("%s", pstr);
    reverseVowels(string);
    printf("%s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `--pc2` since you're moving backwards through the string...

Comment: Start by using a debugger to catch the crash, and locate where in the code it happens.

Comment: Also try using `while(pc1<pc2)` instead of `!=`

Comment: @ritika_13 try my answer

Comment: Add yourself a function: `static inline int is_vowel(int c) { return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'); }` and use `is_vowel(*pc1)` and `is_vowel(*pc2)` in the code.  You'll be grateful when you start to handle upper-case vowels too.  Also learn about `<ctype.h>` — though it does not have an `isvowel()` as standard.  The `_` is not an accident; it avoids using a name reserved for use by the implementation (`isVowel()` would be OK too; `isvowel()` is reserved).  The `inline` is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several answers and comments pointing out the fundamental flaw in your code — that you're incrementing `pc2` instead of decrementing it.  However, I think your algorithm is more complicated than need be.  You could:

- Subject at all times to `pc1 < pc2`:

  - If `pc1` is not pointing at a vowel, increment it
  - If `pc2` is not pointing at a vowel, decrement it
  - If the pointers are different, swap the vowels and adjust the pointers

With test code, and with the addition of an `is_vowel()` function which detects both upper-case and lower-case vowels, I ended up with:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline int is_vowel(int c)
{
    c = tolower(c);
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

static void reverse_vowels(char *string)
{
    char *p1 = string;
    char *p2 = p1 + strlen(p1);     // '\0' is not a vowel

    while (p1 < p2)
    {
        while (p1 < p2 && !is_vowel((unsigned char)*p1))
            p1++;
        while (p1 < p2 && !is_vowel((unsigned char)*p2))
            p2--;
        if (p1 != p2)
        {
            char c = *p1;
            *p1++ = *p2;
            *p2-- = c;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
#ifdef INTERACTIVE
    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("Input:  [%s]\n", line);
        reverse_vowels(line);
        printf("Output: [%s]\n", line);
    }
#else
    char strings[][40] =
    {
        "",
        "a",
        "b",
        "ab",
        "abe",
        "abeci",
        "nnnnummmmmmmmmmmmippppoqq",
        "AbleWasIEreISawElba",
        "A Man, A Plan, A Canal - Panama!"
    };
    enum { NUM_STRINGS = sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
    {
        printf("Input:  [%s]\n", strings[i]);
        reverse_vowels(strings[i]);
        printf("Output: [%s]\n", strings[i]);
    }
#endif /* INTERACTIVE */
    return 0;
}
```

You can compile it with `-DINTERACTIVE` to give you an interactive test, or by default it gives a fixed set of tests.

Default output:

```
Input:  []
Output: []
Input:  [a]
Output: [a]
Input:  [b]
Output: [b]
Input:  [ab]
Output: [ab]
Input:  [abe]
Output: [eba]
Input:  [abeci]
Output: [ibeca]
Input:  [nnnnummmmmmmmmmmmippppoqq]
Output: [nnnnommmmmmmmmmmmippppuqq]
Input:  [AbleWasIEreISawElba]
Output: [ablEWasIerEISawelbA]
Input:  [A Man, A Plan, A Canal - Panama!]
Output: [a Man, a Plan, a CAnal - PAnamA!]
```

Sample interactive session (my program was called `rv61`):

```
$ rv61

Input:  []
Output: []
a
Input:  [a]
Output: [a]
b
Input:  [b]
Output: [b]
ab
Input:  [ab]
Output: [ab]
ae
Input:  [ae]
Output: [ea]
abcde
Input:  [abcde]
Output: [ebcda]
ablewasiereisawelba
Input:  [ablewasiereisawelba]
Output: [ablewasiereisawelba]
palindromic nonsense 
Input:  [palindromic nonsense]
Output: [pelendromic nonsinsa]
vwlsmssng
Input:  [vwlsmssng]
Output: [vwlsmssng]
AManAPlanACanal-Panama!
Input:  [AManAPlanACanal-Panama!]
Output: [aManaPlanaCAnal-PAnamA!]
  a big and complex sentence with multiple words of a number of lengths and so on  
Input:  [  a big and complex sentence with multiple words of a number of lengths and so on  ]
Output: [  o bog and cemplox sentunca woth moltepli wurds if e nember ef longths and si an  ]
$
```

Note that the testing tests a number of degenerate cases — an empty string, a string with no vowels, a string with one vowel, etc.  The palindromic tests benefit from supporting mixed case — it's hard to spot that vowels have been swapped if they're all lower case and the text is a palindrome.

Another test that could be applied is to reverse the vowels twice; the output should be the same as the input.  Conservation tests can be important.  (If you had a sort which didn't preserve all the elements in the array but added random new ones and/or dropped initial ones, you wouldn't be happy.  But that's a topic for another day.)

Having a simple test harness along the lines shown can be helpful for library functions.  Many of my library functions have a `#ifdef TEST` … `#endif` at the end to allow them to be tested for sanity.  The best tests verify that the result is what is expected; these ones are lazy and leave it to visual inspection to validate the output.  If it was a library function, there'd be a header to declare the function which would be `#include`d in the source, and the function would not be `static`.  (My default compilation options require either a declaration of the function before it is defined, or the function must be `static`.  I make functions `static` in sample code like this since there's no other file referencing the function, so there's no need for a header to declare the function, and only headers should declare externally visible functions.)

Note too that the `is_vowel` name is carefully chosen to avoid the reserved names in the C standard:

> Function names that begin with either `is` or `to`, and a lowercase letter may be added to the declarations in the `<ctype.h>` header.

Using `isVowel()` would have been OK too; using `isvowel()` would be using a reserved name.

---

[Bill Woodger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927206/bill-woodger) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125324/reverse-vowels-in-string-in-c/43127711?noredirect=1#comment73336431_43127711):

> Why the comment about '\0' not being a vowel? …

With the code as shown, after the initialization of `p2`, it is true that `*p2 == '\0'`.  The observation the `'\0'` is not a vowel matters if the string is non-empty because if it matched the `is_vowel()` predicate, the null byte could be moved to some point earlier in the string, truncating it.

Suppose the function was `reverse_controls()` instead of `reverse_vowels()` and the test used `iscntrl()` instead of `is_vowel()`. Then the code would have to handle it differently for a non-zero length string because the null byte would be reported as a control character and that would send things awry — it would be swapped with the first other control character (if there was another) in the string, truncating the string.  That is not what's intended.

Comment: Thanks. Code I can read, which I always enjoy :-) . Why the comment about '\0' not being a vowel? Are you just emphasising the '\0' is deliberately ignored? The code reads well, so doesn't need comments, and then the one comment that there is, I can't make sense of in its own terms? It's not a vowel, but since it will never be referenced, that's not relevant, and you could equally have said it is not a porcupine. Bear in mind, I could easily be missing something, as I don't know much more about C than how to spell it.

Comment: @BillWoodger: The comment is there because after the addition, `*p2 == '\0'`, and it is important that `'\0' is not a vowel so `p2` is decremented to find a vowel.  It seems logical to use `p2 = p1 + strlen(p1) - 1;` but then you have to deal with the edge case of the empty string.  This works correctly even with the empty string because the outer loop spots `p1 == p2` and never goes incrementing or decrementing anything.  When I first wrote it, I had special case code for the empty string and an early return and then the `strlen(p1) - 1` code.  As revised, I can avoid the special case.

Comment: Was I wrong in thinking that P1 = P2 for the empty string? So the body of the while would never be entered, so nothing, not even is_vowel, would reference the '\0'?

Comment: @BillWoodger: Maybe the comment is confusing, but I put it there because the issue seemed important.  Suppose the function was `reverse_controls()` and the test used `iscntrl()` instead of `is_vowel()`. Then I would have to handle it differently for a non-zero length string because the null byte would be reported as a control character and that would send things awry — it would be swapped with the first other control character (if there was another) in the string, truncating the string. I think I misled you in my previous comment (because I was mildly confused myself). This is clearer.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. I was concentrating on the special case, and not realising that for all the normal cases it gets to is_vowel. I deal with fixed-length fields, so interesting for me to see different approaches to the treatment of strings.You can rely on the '\0' being there, and relying on it can simplify the code (making it clearer, rather than "shortening" the code in some obscure way).

Comment: Another option would be to have the length of the string passed to the function.  For lengths 0 or 1, the function need do nothing except return.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I wrote so many versions of it that I forgot which one was problematic in a way I couldn't figure out. There was a version of it where I --pc2 it. The problem is part of an exam I took which required me to write one single function that reversed vowels in input string and returned the output (altered input string), so my code was poorly written. Even so, thank you so much for all the help! I wasn't expecting any answers so soon. StackOverflow is like Abed from Community (Abed is a shaman!), you get so much more than what you get asked for! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are incrementing both pointers the one in the 0 position, and the one in the end position. The first pointer should increment, and the second one should decrement, thus instead of doing this:

```
++pc2;
```

You should do this

```
--pc2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring when you are going to increment the pointer variable value of `pc2`, instead of decrementing the pointer variable `pc2` value like this `--pc`.

**Updated**

According to [cleblanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813336/cleblanc)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125324/reverse-vowels-in-string-in-c/43127711#comment73330138_43125479), my previous answer was not working for an input like `abade`, so then I changed the code to fix that problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* reverseVowels(char* str)
{
    char *pc1, *pc2;
    int i;
    pc1 = &str[0];
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0';++i)
        ;
    pc2 = &str[i-1];

    while(pc1<pc2)
    {
      if((*pc1=='a')||(*pc1=='e')||(*pc1=='i')||(*pc1=='o')||(*pc1=='u'))
      {
        while(pc2!=pc1)
        {
            if((*pc2=='a')||(*pc2=='e')||(*pc2=='i')||(*pc2=='o')||(*pc2=='u'))
            {
              char temp;
              temp = *pc1;
              *pc1 = *pc2;
              *pc2 = temp;
              --pc2;
              break;
            }
            else
              --pc2;
        }
        ++pc1;
      }
      else
        ++pc1;
    }
    //return str;
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    char string[20], *pstr;
    scanf("%s", string);
    //pstr = reverseVowels(string);
    //printf("%s", pstr);
    reverseVowels(string);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Super. Can't it get to look a bit better (ie different code)? The problem is really a "typo"-type, and doesn't really help anyone else if they come across it unless they've made the same typo (which is a fluke if they find it)?

Comment: This doesn't work for input `abade`  try `while(pc1<pc2)`

Comment: @cleblanc ya,your right :) according to your input its not working.I'll check it

Comment: @cleblanc ya.ur right ,i updated my answer,now its working

Comment: @BillWoodger Ok ,I'll try :) i can do this with c++

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and to all those who made worthy contributions to it! :)

Comment: @ritika_13 please accept the answer if it is help for you